# How to load ogr2ogr?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, ogr2ogr

I installed ogr2ogr by using `npm i ogr2ogr`, but when I try to call ogr2ogr from TypeScript, I am getting this error. Can anyone explain how to load ogr2ogr in TypeScript?

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-constants/browser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\fs-constants'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/touch/touch.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\touch'
ERROR in ./node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\archiver\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/findit/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\findit'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mkpath/mkpath.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\mkpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/modules/zip.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\modules'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/modules/csv.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\modules'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/modules/util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\modules'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\node_modules\rimraf'
ERROR in ./node_modules/touch/touch.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\touch'
ERROR in ./node_modules/walkdir/walkdir.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\walkdir'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/modules/util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\modules'
ERROR in ./node_modules/archiver/lib/plugins/tar.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\archiver\lib\plugins'
ERROR in ./node_modules/crc32-stream/lib/deflate-crc32-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\crc32-stream\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/decompress-zip/lib/extractors.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\decompress-zip\lib'

Date: 2020-07-01T08:24:43.033Z - Hash: b64823683ce88d1548b1
3 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 42.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.31 MB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 2627ms
: Compiled successfully.

Date: 2020-07-01T08:37:11.803Z - Hash: e40c5c3bb1b1fec5c8bd
3 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 44 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 5.82 MB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 12631ms

ERROR in ./node_modules/fs-constants/browser.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\fs-constants'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/touch/touch.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\touch'
ERROR in ./node_modules/archiver/lib/core.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\archiver\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/findit/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\findit'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\fs.realpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\glob'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/mkpath/mkpath.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\mkpath'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/modules/zip.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\modules'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/modules/csv.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\modules'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/modules/util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\modules'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\node_modules\rimraf'
ERROR in ./node_modules/touch/touch.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\touch'
ERROR in ./node_modules/walkdir/walkdir.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\walkdir'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ogr2ogr/modules/util.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\ogr2ogr\modules'
ERROR in ./node_modules/archiver/lib/plugins/tar.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\archiver\lib\plugins'
ERROR in ./node_modules/crc32-stream/lib/deflate-crc32-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\crc32-stream\lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/decompress-zip/lib/extractors.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'D:\Project\webmaps\node_modules\decompress-zip\lib'
```

Comment: Please share the code showing how you import and use ogr2ogr.

Comment: import * as ogr2ogr from 'ogr2ogr';   console.log(ogr2ogr);